# How to get only date from date-time through linq in c#?

Tags: c#, date, datatable

I have this code:

```
 DataTable dt = DataAccess.GetDataInDataTable(ConnString, "sp_getHolidays", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
List<string> columnDates = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(cols => cols.ColumnName).ToList();
```

This code brings me the list of dates in format : **yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000**.

But I want only in yyyy-MM-dd format. I don't want time. How to get it in the way I want? Or is it even possible through linq or any other way?

Comment: `cols => cols.ColumnName.Substring(0, 10)`

Comment: @mjwills, I hope this will give me yyyy-MM-dd format?

Comment: Can you please run the stored proc in SSMS (SQL Server tooling) and show us a screenshot of the results there? That will help us identify whether the date is in the column name, or in the data inside the column itself.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion @noobprogrammer? Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ColumnName` is of type string not `DateTime`, Split `ColumnName` by space and select first element that is `Date`.

```
List<string> columnDates = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
               .Select(cols => cols.ColumnName.Split(" ").First())
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Hey!  Yes got it. Thank you very much.